# How to check a condition for each row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame containing some numerical values such as this:

```
   col1  col2
0     1     3
1    -2    -4
2     3    -5
```

I wish to have a `col3` which contain:
1  - if all values in the row are > 0,
-1 - if all values in the row are < 0 and
0  - for all other cases

So, my resultant df should look like this:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     1
1    -2    -4    -1
2     3    -5     0
```

Please help me out by letting me know the most Pythonic way to achieve this using Pandas and/or Numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['col3']=np.select([(df.gt(0).all(axis=1)),(df.lt(0).all(axis=1))],[1,-1],0)
print(df)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     1
1    -2    -4    -1
2     3    -5     0
```

*Explanation* as the docs say:

> numpy.select(condlist, choicelist, default=0)
>
> Return an array drawn from elements in choicelist, depending on conditions.

Here the condition list is `(df.gt(0).all(axis=1))` and `(df.lt(0).all(axis=1))` which checks for the 2 conditions you have mentioned. (*For better practice you can just print the condition to check the output*). rest we sequentially place the choices, here 1 and -1. the last parameter is default which is zero by default , you can specify if any other default value is required.

**Performance**:

```
%timeit np.select([(df.gt(0).all(axis=1)),(df.lt(0).all(axis=1))],[1,-1],0)
#414 µs ± 18.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried looking up the documentation of np.select but still could not understand it properly. Could you please explain how this works?

Comment: @SomnathRakshit I have updated my answer with a brief explanation. If you found the answer helpful , please consider upvoting and [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) the answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `df.all()`:

```
df['col3'] = (df > 0).all(axis=1) * 1 + (df < 0).all(axis=1) * -1

print(df)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     1
1    -2    -4    -1
2     3    -5     0
```

Comment: I like this approach. But how does third condition work that sets the default value of 0? Is 0 is the default value in a df?

Comment: For the third case, both products will return 0 (only one of those `all()` calls will return true, or both will be false). So it will be 0+0.

Comment: Ah, that's right. But let's say that col3 needs to be set as strings instead of numbers, e.g. "Positive" instead of 1, "Negative" instead of -1 and "Undecided" instead of 0. How can this be used then?

Comment: @SomnathRakshit There are many ways to do that. One that comes to mind is to apply a lambda over this result

Answer (score 1):

another solution is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 3], [-2, -4], [3, -5]], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df['col3'] = df.gt(0).all(axis=1) * 1 - df.lt(0).all(axis=1) * 1
print(df)

   col1  col2  col3
0     1     3     1
1    -2    -4    -1
2     3    -5     0
```